# Bitcoin Infrastructure in Africa?

Tags: mining-profitability, buy-bitcoins

Bitcoin Infrastructure in Africa: Going by basic infrastructure requirements for mining or trading in bitcoins/cryptocurrencies, is Africa ready?

Answer (score 0):

To state it as simple as possible:

For trading crypto's you just need a good internet connection and a computer (even a tablet or phone could suffice).

For mining you need cheap electricity, good internet connection and a secure location. As well as a decent capital as mining rigs aren't cheap.